# Create HIVE Table with multi character delimiter

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to create a HIVE Table with multi string character as a delimiter such as

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABlE tableex(id INT, name STRING) 
ROW FORMAT delimited fields terminated by ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION '/user/myusername';
```

I want to have delimiter as a multi string like "~*".

Comment: AND ONCE AGAIN, AN SQL QUESTION WITH A SUPERFLUOUS ALL-CAPS TITLE. GEEZ.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`FILELDS TERMINATED BY` does not support multi-character delimiters. The easiest way to do this is to use [`RegexSerDe`](http://hive.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/RegexSerDe.html):

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABlE tableex(id INT, name STRING) 
ROW FORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  "input.regex" = "^(\\d+)~\\*(.*)$"
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE 
LOCATION '/user/myusername';
```

Comment: Thanks Hari, I am aware about SerDe. But the problem with SerDe is that I am not able to create linked server connection on SSMS with Hive Tables. Do you how to resolve that issue?

Comment: I have not worked on SSMS, so I cannot say for sure. But why do you think it is a problem with SerDe? I would think that is a separate problem, isn't it?

Comment: I had a similar issue and was able to build a table successfully with this answer, but ran into issues at query time with aggregations. Some digging and I ended up resolving by changing the "org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe" to "org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe"

Answer (score 11):

Please use **MultiDelimitSerde**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABlE tableex(id INT, name STRING) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("field.delim"="~*")
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/user/myusername';
```

Comment: Is it csv serde , Can it take care of fields having multi-line comments.  if fields escaped with backslash and field quoted within double quotes.