# Putting log files into Hive

Tags: python, hadoop, hive

I have an unstructured file which has data like:

file.log:

```
2014-03-13 US Texas   334    4.985
2014-03-13 US    Minnesota   534    6.544
```

The log file is not tab separated as some fields are tab separated and some are not.

How can I put it into a Hive table?

Hive table schema is:

create table file (dateFact string, country string, state string, id int, value string);

How can I load the log file into the Hive table using Python and or Hadoop commands ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the RegexSerDe, you can use `\s+` to match multiple whitespace types (single spaces, multi spaces, tabs).

I don't have my hive instance in front of me to test, but you should get the idea from the code below.

```
CREATE TABLE file.log (
  dateFact STRING,
  country STRING,
  state STRING,
  id STRING,
  value STRING
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES  (
"input.regex" = "([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\d+)\s+([\d.]+)",
"output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5$s"
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Comment: Hi, if file.log had simply "2014-03-13 US Texas 334 4.985", how to insert it into Hive?

Answer (score 3):

The question is probably a duplicate.

please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931427/create-hive-table-with-multi-character-delimiter) and also this [blog](http://jayunit100.blogspot.in/2013/12/building-hive-table-over.html).

According to the above 2 links, you cannot have multiple delimiters, It is not supported.

But there is a work around. It can be achieved by using a `RegExSerde` .

You need to figure out a regex pattern for your business needs and keep that in serde properties.

Comment: Okay, what if the delimiters were 2 space? How to load data into Hive if each filed in log file has 2 spaces? please provide detail.