# Hive doesn't separate tsv file properly

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a TSV file and trying to load it to hive by;

```
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'   LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
```

Problematic part here though is file contains "02\t\t\t" strings like this.
So that hive does not recognize it as tab separated and doesn't separate them.
I would like to know if there is a way to make hive understand "\t" in a string also should be field separated. I have read a book about it and saw that there are no free serdes for tsv as well.

Example Input Line:

```
8   fp\t\t\t     dj\t\t\t    5  amz ep 02\t\t\t ar\t
```

Cheers,

Comment: Does the file contain both tabs and `\t`, or are all the tabs written directly as `\t`?

Comment: File contains both of them

Comment: plz paste one record line

Comment: Does the solution provided here works for you ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931427/create-hive-table-with-multi-character-delimiter

Comment: Well, then i will have a new question how to create that regex? Maybe this solution would be helpful for me as well. Thank you