# how can i ignore " (double quotes) while loading file in PIG?

Tags: apache-pig, hdfs

I have following data in file

```
"a","b","1","2"
"a","b","4","3"
"a","b","3","1"
```

I am reading this file using below command

```
File1 = LOAD '/path' using PigStorage (',') as (f1:chararray,f2:chararray,f3:int,f4:int)
```

But here it is ignoring the data of field 3 and 4

How to read this file correctly or any way to make PIG skip **'"'**

Additional information i am using  Apache Pig version 0.10.0

Comment: You may use regex for this one, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931427/create-hive-table-with-multi-character-delimiter

Comment: @fxm i can not use hive this is the specific requirement with pig :( (my bad luck)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the [`REPLACE`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/func.html#replace) function (it won't be in one pass though) :

```
file1 = load 'your.csv' using PigStorage(',');
data = foreach file1 generate $0 as (f1:chararray), $1 as (f2:chararray), REPLACE($2, '\\"', '') as (f3:int), REPLACE($3, '\\"', '') as (f4:int);
```

You may also use regexes with [`REGEX_EXTRACT`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/func.html#regex-extract) :

```
file1 = load 'your.csv' using PigStorage(',');
data = foreach file1 generate $0, $1, REGEX_EXTRACT($2, '([0-9]+)', 1), REGEX_EXTRACT($3, '([0-9]+)', 1);
```

Of course, you could erase `"` for f1 and f2 the same way.

Comment: I think the code should be: data = foreach file1 generate $0 as f1, $1 as f2, REPLACE($2, '\\"', '') as f3, REPLACE($3, '\\"', '') as f4; (I m using hive 0.8.0)

Comment: @Dexter you mean letting the types be infered by hive ?

Comment: yes. when I mentioned type as "generate $0 as (f1:chararray)" I got parse error. Then tried "generate $0 as f1", it worked. Sorry as I mentioned hive in above post it should be pig 0.8.0 on CDH3.

Comment: I know this is quite old but this didn't work for me. I have a single chararray field called 'line', and when I do the replace(line, '\\"', '') it returns: Could not resolve replace using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]

Answer (score 1):

Try below (*No need to escape or replace double quotes*) :

```
using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage()
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score 0):

If you have `Jython` installed you could deploy a simple `UDF` to accomplish the job.

**python UDF**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

'''
udf.py
'''

@outputSchema("out:chararray")
def formatter(item):
    chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    nums = '1234567890'
    new_item = item.split('"')[1]
    if new_item in chars:
        output = str(new_item)
    elif new_item in nums:
        output = int(new_item)

    return output
```

**pig script**

```
REGISTER 'udf.py' USING jython as udf;
data = load 'file' USING PigStorage(',') AS (col1:chararray, col2:chararray,
       col3:chararray, col4:chararray);
out = foreach data generate udf.formatter(col1) as a, udf.formatter(col3) as b;
dump out

(a,1)
(a,4)
(a,3)
```

Comment: i forgot to mention this is just a sample data and it may contain special characters.

Answer (score 0):

How about use [REPLACE](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#replace)? if case is this simple?

```
data = LOAD 'YOUR_DATA' Using PigStorage(',') AS (a:chararray, b:chararray, c:chararray, d:chararray) ;

new_data = foreach data generate 
   REPLACE(a, '"', '') AS a,
   REPLACE(b, '"', '') AS b, 
   (int)REPLACE(c, '"', '') AS c:int, 
   (int)REPLACE(d, '"', '') AS d:int;
```

One more tips: If you are loading a csv file, set a correct number format in an Excel like tools might also help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSVExcelStorage loader from Pig.
The double quotes in data are handled by this loader.
You have to register Piggy-bank jar for using this loader.

`Register ${jar_location}/piggybank-0.15.0.jar;`

```
load_data = load '${data_location}' using 
org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage(',');
```

Hope this helps.