# Pig processing incorrect data using piggy bank jars

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a file whose structure is like mentioned below:

**ID,Name,Address**

```
1,"Amrit,kumar",India   
2,"Vaibhav,arora",USA   
3,"Deepika,kumar",Germany
```

Obviously if i give pigStorage(',') the three Fields will get splitted  into 4 and the data spill over.
Alternatives :

1. I tried piggy bank jars but the issue still exist and the data still spills.Please find below the script

   `A11 = LOAD 'File.csv.gz'  USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVLoader()   as (column:type)`
2. I tried Replace fucntiion as well i was having 35k rows the change is not gettting take place for all the rows.Any how the data still spills in this case as well.Column value get shifted to next column.Please find below the referred link.

   [how can i ignore " (double quotes) while loading file in PIG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24554648/])
3. I tried CSVEXCEL Storage and CSV loader as well.

Please suggest what are the things that i can do here. I want to have the name value in a single column.

Comment: What you can do is to write a regex that will replace all instances of `,` with say `|` except the ones that are between `" "` like `1,"a,b",c` should become `1|"a,b"|c` then you can use `PigStorage` to load the data.

Comment: @ philantrovert I can't change the raw file here.

Answer (score 0):

Load it into 4 fields,replace quotes,add a space after the 2nd field,finally concat the 2nd and 3rd field to get the full name in one field/column.No external jars required.

```
A = LOAD 'File.csv.gz' USING PigStorage(',') AS (f1:int,f2:chararray,f3:chararray,f4:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE 
            f1,
            CONCAT(REPLACE(f2,'\\"',''),' ') as f2, -- replace beginning quote and add space at end
            REPLACE(f3,'\\"','') as f3,             -- replace ending quote
            f4;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE 
            f1 as id,
            CONCAT(f2,f3) as name,
            f4 as country;
DUMP C;
```

Comment: We don't need to use replace here because  piggy bank jar is working fine and  it is removing the quotes around column Name .Now the problem come at storing the data because i'm using **pigStorage(',')** .Even if i use concat the data will have commas between it .What would be the best storage  delimitter  to give here or any other suggestions

Comment: @codaholic A working solution is not enough? Why will you have commas if you use concat? pigstorage(',') will split the fields on comma.

Answer (score 0):

Tested this script with your data:

```
-- load as four fields
a = LOAD 'data.txt' using PigStorage(',');

-- removes single quotes from second and third fields
b = foreach a generate $0 as id, REPLACE($1, '"', '') as firstname, REPLACE($2, '"', '') as lastname, $0 as address;

-- combines second and third field with a ',' in between
c = foreach b generate id,  CONCAT(firstname, ',', lastname) as name, address;
```

Now, test the result:

```
test = foreach c generate name;
dump test;
(Amrit,kumar)
(Vaibhav,arora)
(Deepika,kumar)
```