# Hive Table Definition - Multiple space delimiter

Tags: hive, field, delimiter, space

I am defining a hive table where the data has 1 to n spaces between each field.
How do I define the delimiter value in such a case?

I defined the table originally as:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE rtt (
field1 STRING,
field2 STRING,
field3 STRING,
field4 STRING,
field5 STRING,
field6 INT,
field7 FLOAT)
COMMENT 'New data set'

PARTITIONED BY (year INT, month INT, day INT)

ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 

FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '

LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'com.hadoop.mapred.DeprecatedLzoTextInputFormat'

OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'

LOCATION '/test-dir/raw/2014/08/07/';
```

Answer (score -1):

try the REGEX SERDE, e.g., as described in

[Create HIVE Table with multi character delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931427/create-hive-table-with-multi-character-delimiter)

I think the regex you want to use as a delimiter is "\s+"