# How to use multiple delimiters in hive

Tags: hive, delimiter

I have a input data set like this,

"UserID"|"State","City","Country"|"Area Code"

"203448"|"aylesbury, n/a, united kingdom"|\N

Here both , and | acts as a delimiter

How to use both this delimiters while creating table in hive.

Comment: Create your table using `,` as the delimiter and then split your columns on the `|` after the table is made.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931427/create-hive-table-with-multi-character-delimiter

You can refer this.

Comment: try this : https://github.com/sanjivsingh/FixedLengthAndDelimitedSerde

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the approach of ingesting each line of your input file intact into a staging table with a single string column, and then split each input line with a regular expression that will key on both commas and pipes.  For example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS staging;
CREATE TABLE staging (rawdata STRING);
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'test.data' INTO TABLE staging;
-- I put your data into a local file called "test.data" - change your path accordingly
```

So using your data, the staging table now looks like:

```
hive> SELECT * FROM staging;
OK
"UserID"|"State","City","Country"|"Area Code"
"203448"|"aylesbury, n/a, united kingdom"|\N
Time taken: 0.452 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```

Then you can create your final table (I arbitrarily named it "target", replace with your own name):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS target;
CREATE TABLE target AS SELECT
  i[0] AS columnNameA,
  i[1] AS columnNameB,
  i[2] AS columnNameC,
  i[3] AS columnNameD,
  i[4] AS columnNameE
FROM (SELECT split(rawdata, ",|\\|") AS i FROM staging) t;
```

Replace the column names with your desired column headings.  In any case, this is resulting content of the target table after creation (I've piped the displayed result through `sed` to delimit the fields with `::` instead of tabs, which I don't find as readable):

```
# hive -e "select * from target" 2>/dev/null | sed 's/\t/ :: /g'
"UserID" :: "State" :: "City" :: "Country" :: "Area Code"
"203448" :: "aylesbury ::  n/a ::  united kingdom" :: NULL
```

Comment: After struggling with a similar issue for a couple days, I also recommend using Rchang's answer to handle any unique delimiter string when importing into Hive.

Comment: "row" is in the hive keyword list.   Instead of "AS row FROM staging" use something like "AS i FROM staging" and then change row[0]..row[4] to i[0]..i[4].  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL