# How to create Hive table for special formated data

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have text files that i want to load into Hive table.

Format of the data is like below

```
Id|^|SegmId|^|geographyId|^|Sequence|^|Subtracted|^|FFAction|!|
4295875876|^|3|^|110170|^|1|^|False|^|I|!|
4295876137|^|2|^|110170|^|1|^|False|^|I|!|
4295876137|^|8|^|100219|^|1|^|False|^|I|!|
```

I want to create a table in Hive for this kind of data.

Can you please suggest how to create table for this?

This is what I have tried but getting null (also please suggest us the data type for the columns):

```
create table if not exists GeographicSegment 
(
    Id int,
    SegId int,
    geographyId int,
    Sequence int,
    Subtracted String,
    FFAction String
) row format delimited fields terminated by '|!|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has worked for me

row format SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("field.delim"="|^|") tblproperties

Comment: When the data has special characters like trademark symbol (®) the last character of the column is getting truncated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your fields are terminated by `'|^|'` and your lines are terminated by `'|!|\n'`

Answer (score 0):

Hive does not support multiple character as delimiter,

you can find the way to handle it here,

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931427/create-hive-table-with-multi-character-delimiter)

Regarding the data type what you are doing is correct except the first column ID. The value present is more than the range of INT. it can be BIGINT.