# Does the MultiDelimitSerde support NULL DEFINED AS clause?

Tags: sql, hive, bigdata, hiveql

This [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931427/create-hive-table-with-multi-character-delimiter)  shows that we can use multi-character delimiter in Hive.

But can we also specify the NULL value?

I tried the following hive sql which returns an error:

```
CREATE TABLE temp
( a STRING, b STRING)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("field.delim"="@#")
NULL DEFINED AS 'NULL'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

The error:

```
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 5:0 missing EOF at 'NULL' near ')' (state=42000,code=40000)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option to use **NULL DEFINED AS 'NULL'** is available when we are using a ROW FORMAT **DELIMITED** option. Here we are using a ROW FORMAT SERDE option so we need to explicitly pass the property **serialization.null.format**.

you can use the below query by setting the property value of serialization.null.format:

```
CREATE TABLE temp
( a STRING, b STRING)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("field.delim"="@#",'serialization.null.format'='NULL')
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

For more information you can refer [Hive DDL](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL) reference guide. [MultiDelimitSerde](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/contrib/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/contrib/serde2/MultiDelimitSerDe.java#L67) source code.

```
HIVE DDL GUIDE:

row_format
  : DELIMITED [FIELDS TERMINATED BY char [ESCAPED BY char]] [COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY char]
        [MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY char] [LINES TERMINATED BY char]
        [NULL DEFINED AS char]   -- (Note: Available in Hive 0.13 and later)
  | SERDE serde_name [WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (property_name=property_value, property_name=property_value, ...)]
```